# Bootstrap 4 Multi Select Not Working Inside Modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get a bootstrap multi-select dropdown working inside a Bootstrap modal. When the modal pop's up this css:

```
select.bs-select-hidden, .bootstrap-select > select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
    display: none !important;
}
```

is being applied to the dropdown:

```
<select name="adminFoci" class="groupSelect" id="adminFoci" required>
                    <option value="default">Choose a Foci</option>
                    <c:forEach items="${foci}" var="focus">
                        <option name="${focus.focusName}" value="${focus.focusName}">${focus.focusName}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
```

The dropdown is invisible, and by unchecking `display: none !important;` the options appear however they are not formatted according to the bootstrap/select css. The dropdown works fine when it is placed outside of the modal.
Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="adminModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered " role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="adminModalTitle">Details</h5>
                    <c:if test="${message != null}">
                        <p>${message}</p>
                    </c:if>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="modalForm"></form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalSubmit" form="modalForm">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried [re-initializing .selectpicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954785/bootstrap-select-didnt-show-on-page-load) all three ways shown in the answers both on DOM load and when my modal pops up, but no difference was made.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before working on modal. But I solved it by loading anything else before executing the code `display: none;`

So if I'm handling this, remove this code for now:

```
select.bs-select-hidden, .bootstrap-select > select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and use Javascript/JQuery onload:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.bs-select-hidden, .bootstrap-select select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker').css('display','none');
});
```

Well ofc, using this code, those elemets will show while loading, If it bothers you, you can apply hidden visibility first:

CSS:

```
select.bs-select-hidden, .bootstrap-select > select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* It's there but invisible, so it loads. */
}
```

and Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.bs-select-hidden, .bootstrap-select select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker').css({'visibility':'visible','display':'none'});
});
```

Comment: The ' display: none !important;' is coming from the bootstrap css module though, how do I prevent it from loading? On top of that, when I deselect this line in dev tools the select box still looks all funky and weird

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AJAX to load partial views returned from my Spring controller. My modal is what was being partially loaded onto the main page and I believe because of this the select picker was being initialized before the modal rendered and hence `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` was not working as the script was included in the main page.

By adding the following to my partial modal view I have since been able to get the select picker to correctly initialize.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```